# how to implement "Select/Unselect" for the "select_tag" with multi-select feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have used the "select_tag" for a multi-select field:

```
%td
    =select_tag('cars',options_from_collection_for_select(@cars, 'id', 'name'), {:multiple=>true,:size => 10})
```

It is fine, **BUT**, after user selected the options, I would like to have the feature that "*After selection, if user click somewhere else all the selected options are return back to unselected*", that's the multi-select field is back to unselected.

How to do this if I use `select_tag`??

Answer (score 0):

First–off, this question has nothing to do with Rails or your usage of the `select` tag. 
You can handle this on the client side with a sprinkle of Javascript — here's an example that uses jQuery:

```
$('select').blur(function(){
    $('option', this).attr('selected', false); 
});

// This seems to work as well, haven't tested in anyhow further, though
$('select').blur(function(){
    $(this).val('');
});
```

You can see it in action here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/jZNAn/1